# Read Hex from a file and convert 2 Bytes into Signed int

Tags: c

I have a file in this format:

```
F2,80,FF,CF,0F,00,A2,XXXX,XXXX,XXXX,01FE,00
```

I need to take bytes 3 and 4 and combine them into a signed integer.

For example I should extract `FF` and `CF` and combine them to `0xFFCF`. This should give me a signed value of `-49`.

The code that I have is here:

```
int main()
{
 char buffer[1024] ;
 char *record,*line;
 uint8_t val;
 uint8_t msb, lsb; 
 int16_t rate;
 int i=0,j=0;
 int mat[100][100];
 FILE *fstream = fopen("log1.txt","r");
 if(fstream == NULL)
 {
   printf("\n file opening failed ");
   return -1 ;
 }

while((line=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fstream))!=NULL)
{
 record = strtok(line,",");
 int count = 0;
 while(record != NULL)
 {
    count++;
    if (count == 3)
    { 
        printf("string:%s\n", record);
        sscanf(record, "%02X", &msb);

        printf("MSB: %01X\n",msb) ;    
    }
    if (count == 4)
    {
        printf("string:%s\n", record);
        sscanf(record, "%02X", &lsb);
        printf("lsb: %01X\n",lsb);  
    }
    if (count == 5)
    {
    int16_t value = (short)(((msb) & 0xFF) << 8 | (lsb) & 0xFF);
    printf("rate: %.2f\n", value*0.03125);
        getchar();
    }
    record = strtok(NULL,",");
 }
 ++i ;
}
return 0;
}
```

The exact output I see from my code is:

```
string:FF
MSB: FF
string:CD
lsb: CD
HEX: 00CD
rate: 6.41
```

I would expect rate to come out as: `-1.59`

I never seem to see negative numbers, and the values I get are too small.

Comment: why do you think 0xFFCF should be a negative integer?

Comment: I think it should give 65487 as output.

Comment: change `int16_t value = (short)(((msb) & 0xFF) << 8 | (lsb) & 0xFF);` to `int value = (((msb) & 0xFF) << 8 | (lsb) & 0xFF);` or to `long value = (((msb) & 0xFF) << 8 | (lsb) & 0xFF);`

Comment: What do you see from your `printf` output? How are `msb` and `lsb` defined? What is `short` for your compiler and how does it differ from `int16_t`, what's the reason for a different type for the cast? What exact result do you get, `-1.53125`?

Comment: Unfortunately the suggested changes haven't worked. I've added more info to the question

Comment: @Kells1986 please edit your question and add you desired output for a given input line.

Comment: The posted code does not output "HEX: 00CD", so "The _exact_ output" is suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using different variable types to try and get the behaviour that you want, how about just being explicit about it? Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int msb = 0xff;
    int lsb = 0xcf;

    int value = (((msb & 0xff) << 8) | (lsb & 0xff));
    if (value >= 0x8000) value = -(0x10000 - value);

    printf("%d\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got the code to work:

```
int16_t hexToInt(char* msb, char* lsb)
{
    char toparse[50];
    strcpy(toparse, msb);
    strcat(toparse,lsb);

    int16_t number = (int16_t)strtol(toparse, NULL, 16);
    return number;
}


int main()
{
char buffer[1024] ;
char *record,*line;
uint8_t val;
char msb[16], lsb[16]; 
int16_t rate;

FILE *fstream = fopen("log1.txt","r");
if(fstream == NULL)
{
  printf("\n file opening failed ");
  return -1 ;
}

while((line=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fstream))!=NULL)
{
 record = strtok(line,",");
 int count = 0;
 while(record != NULL)
 {
    count++;
    if (count == 3)
    { 
        printf("string:%s\n", record);
        strcpy(msb, record);


    }
    if (count == 4)
    {
        printf("string:%s\n", record);
        strcpy(lsb,record);

    }
    if (count == 5)
    {
        int16_t value = hexToInt(msb,lsb);
        printf("rate: %.2f\n", value*0.03125);
        getchar();
    }
    record = strtok(NULL,",");
  }
  ++i ;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The posts has "expect rate to come out as: -15.9".  What does this code output? "-1.53"?

Answer (score 0):

The value is indeed `0xFFCF`, but when multiplying with `0.03125` it is promoted to higher datatype because of which value looses its signedness.

Just change

```
printf("rate: %.2f\n", value*0.03125);
```

to

```
printf("rate: %.2f\n", ((short)value*0.03125));
```

With value being `-49 or 0xFFCF` the output will be

```
rate: -1.53
```

Answer (score 0):

Code has undefined behavior.  OP's code attempts to save an `int` sized result into 1-byte locations.  A good compiler or one with warnings enabled would warn of this issue.

```
uint8_t msb, lsb; 
...
sscanf(record, "%02X", &msb);
sscanf(record, "%02X", &lsb);
```

Code could use the correct `scanf()` specifier

```
#include <inttypes.h>
sscanf(record, "%02" SCNx8, &msb);
sscanf(record, "%02" SCNx8, &lsb);
```

or simply a different type

```
unsigned msb, lsb; 
...
sscanf(record, "%02X", &msb);
sscanf(record, "%02X", &lsb);
```

---

OP's conversion is suspect:

```
uint8_t msb, lsb; 
int16_t value = (short)(((msb) & 0xFF) << 8 | (lsb) & 0xFF);
printf("rate: %.2f\n", value*0.03125);
```

Suggest something like [@John Bickers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32047158/2410359)  The following works even if `int` is 16-bit.

```
long value = msb;
value <<= 8;
value += lsb;
if (value >= 0x8000) value -= 0x10000;
printf("value %ld\n", value);
// -49 *  0.03125 --> "-1.53"
printf("rate: %.2f\n", value * 0.03125);
```

---

Since OP expects a scaled out of -15.6 from -49, perhaps scaling by 1/pi is needed rather than `* 0.03125`?